# What is the reason for slanting of (Solar) analemma?

Tags: astronomy

Why is a (solar) [analemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma), photographed (Multiple exposure imagery)in the morning or afternoon at latitudes other than geographical poles or the equator, slanted?

[image: Afternoon analemma photo taken in 1998–99 in Murray Hill, New Jersey, USA, by Jack Fishburn - Wikipedia]

(For further examples of slanting see this imagery: https://www.perseus.gr/Astro-Solar-Analemma.htm)

Comment: An analemma diagram is closely related to a [sundial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial). Do you understand why the [hour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour_angle) on a sundial are slanted?

Comment: @PM 2Ring You mean the slanting of gnomon?

Comment: @PM 2Ring I don't understand why gnomon shall be parallel to the axis of rotation of Earth for uniform measurement of time. Isn't the angular velocity of the shadow the same whatever the angle gnome is slanted?

Comment: The slanted edge of the gnomon is called the style. On the hour, the shadow of the style falls along the corresponding hour line. The simplest sundial is the equatorial dial, which has the dial plate parallel to the equator. Its gnomon is a rod through the centre of the plate, parallel to the polar axis. All other hour angle dials are simply projections of the equatorial dial onto other planes.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Regarding your earlier comment, If the gnomon is already parallel to the polar axis, why the edge should also be slanted?

Comment: @PM 2Ring OK ;) . But can you kindly explain why it matters to be parallel to the axis? I mean If angular velocity is the same doesn't the shadow travel at a uniform circular distance per hour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150785/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-jacob-miller).

Comment: This question has answers here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55703/54451